# Return a value inside a CompletableFuture in another CompletableFuture and return that future

Tags: java, completable-future, futuretask

I want to get a value inside a CompletableFuture (in this case clonedWorld) in another CompletableFuture and return that future. This is my code, and I'm stuck here:

```
@Override
public CompletableFuture<SlimeWorld> asyncCloneWorld(String worldName, String newWorld) {
    loadWorldAsync(worldName).whenComplete((slimeWorld, throwable) -> {
        if (throwable != null || slimeWorld.isEmpty()) {
            plugin.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Impossibile caricare il mondo template!", throwable);
            return;
        }
        try {
            SlimeWorld clonedWorld = slimeWorld.get().clone(newWorld, loader, true);
        } catch (IOException | WorldAlreadyExistsException e) {
            plugin.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Non è stato possibile clonare il mondo: " + worldName, e);
        }
    });
  return ?;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `whenComplete` which returns a `CompletableFuture<Void>`. Use one of the other methods like `thenApply` or `handle` to return a transformed value.

Comment: Ok, but how can I use clonedWorld as a return value of the new CompletableFuture returned in the method?

Comment: `return clonedWorld;` within the `Function`/`BiFunction` passed to those methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `whenComplete()` only takes a `BiConsumer` as parameter, which cannot handle the result of the returned `CompletableFuture` – except if an exception is thrown.

The appropriate method to use if you want to change the result (here from something like `Optional<SlimeWorld>` or an exception to just `SlimeWorld` or `null`) is [`handle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-). The lambda passed to `handle()` should thus return the final result (the cloned world or `null`).

And as `CompletableFuture` is a fluent API, you can just return the result of the `handle()` call from `asyncCloneWorld()`:

```
public CompletableFuture<SlimeWorld> asyncCloneWorld(String worldName, String newWorld) {
    return loadWorldAsync(worldName).handle((slimeWorld, throwable) -> {
        if (throwable != null || slimeWorld.isEmpty()) {
            plugin.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Impossibile caricare il mondo template!", throwable);
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return slimeWorld.get().clone(newWorld, loader, true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            plugin.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Non è stato possibile clonare il mondo: " + worldName, e);
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```